# Where are XCode 3 environment variables defined?

Tags: environment-variables, osx-mavericks, xcode3.2

On my Mac OS 10.9.3, I have a C++ XCode 3 project on which, I don't know where, an environment variable is set (say MYVAR). I can see it when I launch a build in a command line using xcodebuild from my terminal, in the output:

```
...
setenv MYVAR "My Value"
...
```

This variable is absolutely unset from all my global environment variables of my OS (.bashprofile, .profile, launchd.conf, profile, .bashrc, etc.) . When I type

```
echo $MYVAR
```

in a terminal, it displays an empty result.

So, where can be this variable defined? I searched in **Source tree** variables, in my **pbxproj** file, in all my **xcconfig**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have detailed it in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6427836).

In a few words, the variables remained present in three different preferences files:

```
codebuild.plist
com.apple.XCode.plist
com.apple.dt.XCode.plist
```

They can be found in your **/Library/Preferences**.

After restarting my computer, the variable has disappeared.

Comment: Would you tell me where /Library/Preferences is located exactly?

Comment: At that time, I was on MacOS X 10.6. To find the folder on this OS, open your terminal and type `cd /Library/Preferences`